# ESENT database engine file access denied

Tags: c#, .net, esent

I am trying to using the ESENT windows database with the [managedesent](http://managedesent.codeplex.com) library but I always get the error

```
Error FileAccessDenied (JET_errFileAccessDenied, Cannot access file, the file is locked or in use)
```

The code to open the database is

```
m_Dictionary = new PersistentDictionary<string, PropertyStruct>("BaseEstateCachedPropertySummary2");
```

I am testing this on Windows 7 and the application is an ASP.NET application. Does anyone have any ideas about this, documentation is pretty slim.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an answer. Apparently I didn't have write permissions to the default directory where it puts the database so I had to specify the full path such as.

```
m_Dictionary = new PersistentDictionary<string, PropertyStruct>(@"c:\Data\BaseEstateCachedPropertySummary2");
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to open an existing database used by another service (e.g. the Windows Update database)? Esent databases are single-process only so you have to stop any other processes that are using the same database.

Comment: I am not trying to open an existing database like that. I have added the code above.